# Cancel an asynchronous jquery file upload during the upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I need to be able to cancel an upload while it is uploading. I have found https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#how-to-cancel-an-upload however that depends on you not using the options object. I am using the options object.

When you do

```
var jqXHR = $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: filesList})
```

it returns an object you can call `.abort()` on.

However, when you just use the options object

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({url:'...',add: function(e, data){data.submit();}});
```

then it returns the jquery selector for `'#fileupload'`

I'm lost as to how to trigger a cancel upload after you do `data.submit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, the object is returned on the data.submit();

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  url:'...',
  add: function(e, data){
    var jqXHR = data.submit();

    // Setup event handler
    form.find('.cancel_upload').on('click', function(){
      jqXHR.abort();
    });
  }
});
```

And that is how you can get to the abort method.